# How to reduce Reactive Native app memory usage in Android

Tags: android, react-native

As soon as I run my app, it takes up about 250MB of memory.
I checked the heap of android studio
`byte [], char [], long []` occupy a huge amount of memory.
What can I do to my reactive code to reduce the memory equivalent of `byte []`?

I don't know anything because it is only represented as `byte []`.[image]

Comment: Not use react native.  Its a memory hog.  Other than that, the question is unanswerable without pretty much your entire app's code.  We have no idea what the memory is being used in.  They byte arrays are probably bitmaps for the biggest ones though.  That's fairly normal in Android

Comment: Share some more details. for better understanding..